# Want to change gtkfilechooser

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gnome, vala

[image]

I wish to change this popup for every program calling

```
public class OpenFileDialog : FileChooserDialog {
```

Ideally it would involve removing desktop and changing search etc. I was just hoping somebody knew where the underlying files are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI layout for the file chooser dialog is in gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c